# SQL SELECT CASE WHEN SUM

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum

I want to apply a query using CASE based on SUM of the group by clause.

My Table would look something like:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      customerId     |     duration     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        A12345       |         5        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        A12345       |         10       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        A65421       |         5        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

and want it to output

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      sum(duration)  | count(customerId)|
|---------------------|------------------|
|        0-5          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        5-10         |         0        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        10+          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

My current SQL is something like:

```
select
       case
            when sum(duration) between 0 and 5 then '0-5'
            when sum(duration) between 5 and 10 then '5-10'
            else '10+'
        end as bucket,
       count(customerId)
from table
group by 1, customerid
```

but this gives me

> Invalid operation: aggregates not allowed in GROUP BY clause;

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The data type of `duration` matters. And possibly your version of Postgres. Also, "0-5" and "5-10" overlap. Where is 5 (exactly) supposed to be counted?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter datatype of `duration` is an INTEGER. Deciding on 5 can be done either, and isn't the focus here. 0-5, 6-10, if that makes anything clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need nested aggregation:

```
select -- then count the number of rows per bucket
   bucket,
   count(*)
from 
 ( -- aggregate the duration per customer first
   select customerid, 
          case
            when sum(duration) between 0 and 5 then '0-5'
            when sum(duration) between 5 and 10 then '5-10'
            else '10+'
        end as bucket
   from table
   group by customerid
 ) as dt
group by bucket
```

Comment: Very concise and elegant! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Group By 1 --> will Group by the first column, that has aggregate function `sum()`
That is not allowed, 
So the query should be as follows

```
Select Case when duration between 0 and 5 then '0-5'
        when duration between 0 and 5 then '5-10'
        Else '10+'
        end as bucket,
        count(customerId) customerIdCount
From
(
    select
          customerid, sum(duration) as duration
    from table1
    group by customerid
) Q
Group by Case when duration between 0 and 5 then '0-5'
    when duration between 0 and 5 then '5-10'
    Else '10+'
    end
```

If you desire to get the exact results as shown in your question, you need to put all those bucket values to a table and join that

```
Select t1.bucket, coalesce(customerIdCount,0) from table2 t1
Left Join 
(
    Select Case when duration between 0 and 5 then '0-5'
            when duration between 0 and 5 then '5-10'
            Else '10+'
            end as bucket,
            count(customerId) customerIdCount
    From
    (
        select
              customerid, sum(duration) as duration
        from table1
        group by customerid
    ) Q
    Group by Case when duration between 0 and 5 then '0-5'
        when duration between 0 and 5 then '5-10'
        Else '10+'
        end
) r on t1.bucket = r.bucket
;
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qRuBKMwMJYKVGKaEMSK12W/0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by customers first, like dnoeth already suggested. But consider a modified approach:

```
SELECT CASE bucket
         WHEN 0 THEN '0-5'  -- 5 excluded
         WHEN 1 THEN '5-10' -- 10 excluded
         ELSE        '10+'
       END AS sum_duration
     , count(*) AS customers
FROM  (
   SELECT customerid
        , trunc(sum(duration))::int / 5 AS bucket -- ①
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY customerid
   ) sub
GROUP  BY bucket;
```

① Since you form buckets of *5*, we can use [**integer division**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html) to get an integer bucket. Should be a bit shorter / faster (especially with more buckets). If `duration` is an `integer` type you can simplify:

```
...
        , sum(duration) / 5 AS bucket
..
```

Either way *5* (exactly) ends up in the group "5-10" exclusively, etc. - fixing a corner case bug in your original which would double-count. It's often overlooked that [`BETWEEN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE) includes lower and upper bound and is typically [only useful with discrete data types](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29).

Comment: Well, the CASE prevents double-counting (`when sum(duration) <= 10 then '5-10'` would be shorter). And for equi-width histograms (with large numbers of buckets) there's `width_bucket(duration, 0,10,2)`