# Work around on Sum(case when sum(x)>y) included in a Group by

Tags: group-by, sql-server-2012, case

Here is a similar Table I am working with:

| Username | Id | Columnx | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| person | 00201 | x | 20022 |
| person | 00201 | x | 2222 |
| person3 | 00203 | x | 2211 |

Here is the result I want to get to:

| Username | Id | Test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| person | 00201 | 2 |
| person3 | 00203 | 1 |

As the title says I am trying to find a work around for something similar to this:

```
SELECT 
USERNAME
,IDS
,Sum(CASE 
    WHEN Sum(Value) >= 1000
        AND Columnx = 'x'
    THEN 1
        Else 0
        END) AS Test
Group by
Username
,IDs
```

I keep getting the error "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery." Which makes sense. But I wondering if there is a way to have a similar result to this while avoiding the error.

My reasoning for doing it this way is that I am trying to get a total count of rows that meet the cases and then group it by users to get a stat page about each user of how many times they met these requirements.

I have thought about another avenue of using `count()` and `having` but I have a lot more case columns that would not work because they focus on other items and having `WHEN Sum(Value) >= 1000` would mess with those counts.

I also saw [SQL SELECT CASE WHEN SUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61899913/sql-select-case-when-sum) this, I am wondering if this would work or would it throw off my other counts?

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely. Your required logic is really unclear. How would you sum a sum? Perhaps you want a window function over the whole table `SUM(CASE WHEN SUM(Value) >= 1000 AND Columnx = 'x' THEN 1 END)` or maybe you want to calculate a window function first? Or maybe you want to aggregate on two levels?

Comment: Sorry about that. Hindsight is 2020 sorry for not including that. I added the two tables. The window function would work then I guess as the value would just be a generated column in the table then right?

Comment: I'm really confused now. Isn't your desired result just conditional aggregation `COUNT(CASE WHEN Value >= 1000 AND Columnx = 'x' THEN 1 END)` no window function needed?